# Complexity of determinant algorithms

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, computational-complexity

**Question**: Name two methods to compute the determinant of an
$n × n$ matrix. For each method, compute the complexity of the algorithm; i.e. count the expected number of multiplications to be performed in the algorithm. The result should be in terms of n.

The problem is that this is a linear algebra course, that's why i am inclined to believe that there will not be "big-oh" in the solution. So far I have tried to calculate for LU Decomposition yet, i couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Laplace expansion, which is the common algorithm students learn is $O(n!)$. But LU Decomposition is $O(n^3)$ since both matrices are triangular and you only need to multiply the diagonal elements together to get the determinant.

Comment: When using LU Decomposition, doesn't with multiply n-many diagonal elemnents of the upper triangular matrix U? How do we get $O(n^3)$?

Comment: In order to actually decompose the matrix, we need to do $O(n^3)$ operations.